# Apexcharts: Changing opacity of squares when mouseover a series label (:: hover)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts, apexcharts

I have a heatmap chart using apex-charts (https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/heatmap-charts/).

[image: picture]

When i mouseover a series label **(1)** the color stays the same **(2)** and change opacity of the others series **(3)**.

I would like to **change the opacity of other series (3) way lower**, something like 5% of opacity. How i can change that using apex-charts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS responsible for rendering *"other series (3)"* is:

```css
.legend-mouseover-inactive {
  transition: .15s ease all;
  opacity: .2;
}
```

To change the `opacity` to `5%` use:

```css
.legend-mouseover-inactive {
  opacity: .05;
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-heatmap-color-range-kdwibx?file=/src/style.css).